# Finding a cluster of 1s in a sequence

Tags: c#, .net, data-processing

From an image preprocessing tool, I get a sequence of 0's and 1's, where 1's indicate that the preprocessing tool has found what I'm looking for. In an ideal world, this would look something like this:

00000000000000001111111000000000000000000

I now need to find the "middle" position of the 1's, i.e.

00000000000000000001000000000000000000000

This would be fairly simple (iterate through the list, get the transition to 1 and the transition to 0 and calculate the middle from those two positions.

HOWEVER, here's where it gets a bit tricky:

The sequence usually looks more like:

0000100001000101000100000011110110111100000000001000101000000

I.e. there is a substantial amount of "noise".

I assume I could assume, that any "lone" 1 or "lone" 0 is probably noise and flip it, but I was wondering whether there is a more elegant and robust way of finding "the most likely cluster of 1's" in a random sequence?

Comment: Perhaps you want the longest running sequence of ones?

Comment: depends no how you _define_ "the most likely cluster of 1's". what you might try is a moving average filter.

Comment: You have Geusian Noise.  A simple algorithm to get center of noise is to add the number of 1's in a row to a count and subtract number of zeroes in a row to the count.  Then get largest count.  Do not let count go below zero.  So starting at 1111011011110000000000  the count would be 0,4,3,6,5,9,0.  An improvement would to do a standard deviation of the numbers 4,3,6,5,9 which is really getting the center of a bell curve (Normainl Distribution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a running sum of the series both in forward and reverse order. Where the two series are equal will be your middle. In this example both series equal 9 at index 30.

| Index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 | 37 | 38 | 39 | 40 | 41 | 42 | 43 | 44 | 45 | 46 | 47 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 51 | 52 | 53 | 54 | 55 | 56 | 57 | 58 | 59 | 60 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Original | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Sum Series | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | **9** | 10 | 11 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 15 | 16 | 16 | 16 | 16 | 17 | 17 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 |
| Reverse Sum Series | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 17 | 17 | 17 | 17 | 17 | 16 | 16 | 16 | 16 | 15 | 15 | 14 | 14 | 14 | 14 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 12 | 11 | 10 | **9** | 9 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Summed Sums | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 19 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 19 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 19 | 18 | 19 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 19 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 19 | 19 | 19 | 19 | 18 | 19 | 19 | 18 | 19 | 19 | 19 | 19 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 19 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 19 | 18 | 19 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 18 |

If you look at a graph of the series it is quite literally an "X marks the spot" situation.
[Series Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91HVA.png)